# Find the number of valid logins for each user in PieCloudDB

Tags: sql

I have a table that records the time a user logs into a platform. I now want to know how many valid logins each user has. The number of valid times means that **the interval from the last valid login** is not less than 10 minutes. It is assumed that each user's first login is a valid login.

For example, in the following table, the number of valid logins for user 1 is 4 times(13:28,13:39,13:51,14:01), for user 2 is 3 times(16:25,17:55,18:30), and for user 3 is 2 times(14:15,15:52).

| user_id | login_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13:28 |
| 1 | 13:31 |
| 1 | 13:33 |
| 1 | 13:39 |
| 1 | 13:42 |
| 1 | 13:48 |
| 1 | 13:51 |
| 1 | 14:01 |
| 2 | 16:25 |
| 2 | 17:55 |
| 2 | 18:30 |
| 3 | 14:15 |
| 3 | 14:16 |
| 3 | 15:52 |

The problem now is that I don’t know how to find `the last valid login` so that to find the next goal. I tried to write a plan but the output results were incorrect. I have no idea to solve this problem now.

Comment: I guess, you need to clarify if this PieCloudDB supports window-functions like LEAD/LAG

Answer (score 0):

Record first login as initial value, then use CTE to do recursive query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ranked_logins AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    login_time,
    1 AS login_rank
  FROM
    user_logins
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM user_logins prev
      WHERE prev.user_id = user_logins.user_id
      AND prev.login_time > user_logins.login_time - INTERVAL '10 minutes'
      AND prev.login_time < user_logins.login_time
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ul.user_id,
    ul.login_time,
    rl.login_rank + 1
  FROM
    user_logins ul
  JOIN
    ranked_logins rl ON ul.user_id = rl.user_id
    AND ul.login_time > rl.login_time
    AND ul.login_time - INTERVAL '10 minutes' >= rl.login_time
)
SELECT
  user_id,
  MAX(login_rank) AS valid_login_count
FROM
  ranked_logins
GROUP BY
  user_id
ORDER BY
  user_id
```

Test in PieCloudDB cloud platform, it will get the results:

| user_id | valid_login_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |